# What is the best layout/container for a golf scorecard interface?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an interface to track golf scores. I am not sure what is the best approach to display all 18 holes' scores for 4 players along with the title heading on top and the total score heading at the bottom.
I have a Data Class that looks like this:

```
data class Scorecard(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val score_card_id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(index = true) val round_id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(index = true) val player_id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(index = true) val tee_box_id: Int,
        var hole1_score: Int,
        var hole2_score: Int,
        var hole3_score: Int,
        var hole4_score: Int,
        var hole5_score: Int,
        var hole6_score: Int,
        var hole7_score: Int,
        var hole8_score: Int,
        var hole9_score: Int,
        var hole10_score: Int?,
        var hole11_score: Int?,
        var hole12_score: Int?,
        var hole13_score: Int?,
        var hole14_score: Int?,
        var hole15_score: Int?,
        var hole16_score: Int?,
        var hole17_score: Int?,
        var hole18_score: Int?
)
```

I know that the title heading and the total score heading can be static.

Here is what I got so far
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrqB8.png

Any suggestion on what layout/container to use is extremely useful.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Hole and Par from the top.
Use a `CardView`/`Recyclerview` to display each hole in a list.

Example: The Hole 9 Card will have 3 values.

Hole: 9

Par: 4 <- Inserted at pre-game

Score: ? <- User inputs this after round.

As the game goes along each player. Inputs their results into their List of cards.

Clicking P1 will load Player 1 Cards that display all 18 holes.

Clicking P2 will load Player 2 Cards that display all 18 holes.